# Set different spacing between barcode label rows in Telerik reporting

Tags: telerik-reporting

My Telerik barcode report has 3 rows by 2 columns, meaning 6 barcode labels on a page. Normally reporting puts the same spacing between all rows but I would like different spacing between rows on report. For example, say 0.5 space between first and second row and 1.5 space between second and third row.

How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple using Telerik's report designer, just click on the field and set the amount of padding. Is there some reason your unable to use the Report Designer?

http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/ui-report-designer.html